# Catcall due [calculated]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calculated): 106 questions with no clear common topic, no followers, and no tag wiki.

Since so much of programming involves calculating something or another, I don't see how this tag could be helpful.

Comment: This tag's remaining usefulness has been [calculated].

Comment: That wasn't a very calculated title :(

Comment: Wait till you have 2000 rep, then you can burn it yourself. When you do, fix all the other things with the posts. If some posts should be closed or deleted, don't remove the tag, but go to the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room to get support for closing and deleting.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I fully support your last sentence :D

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist thanks, fixed

Comment: @Trobbins it's an anagram.

Comment: Catcall due? Really? You didn't even consider "Lacteal cud?"

Comment: @Trobbins So ominous a comment! Indeed, the [writing is on the wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belshazzar's_feast#Narrative_summary) for this tag. _MENE, MENE, TEKEL, PARSIN. Mene: SO has [calculated] the days of your reign and brought it to an end. Tekel: Your usefulness has been [calculated] and found wanting. Parsin: Your kingdom is [calculated] and given to the mEditors and Burninators._

Comment: I calculate that there are just 50 [tag:calculated] questions left.  _(Oh, all right; SO calculates…)_  Someone else can deal with removing the remaining tags.  It won't take long.

Comment: There are no more questions to be [[tag:calculated]]!

Comment: Scrubbed this tag, will be, in 5 hours more.

Comment: And for non-native English speakers: Catcall = *a shrill whistle or shout of disapproval made at a public meeting or performance.*

Comment: @JanDoggen Not to be confused with the (IMO more common) meaning: "make a whistle, shout, or comment of a sexual nature to a woman passing by." Frequently associated with construction workers. When I first read the title, I thought we were trying to hit on tags now. :P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Between the efforts of [Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao) and [Jonathan Leffler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) and sundry (at present unknown) other helpers, the [calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calculated) tag <s>is about to</s> has  hit the dustbin of history.

[image: ***TROGDOR***]

Comment: And it is done!

Comment: Added the most required element in any *burnination* answer. :)