# Subtract [calculation]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I recently encountered the [calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calculation) tag. The tag doesn't really add anything meaningful and can't stand on it's own, so I'd like to see it burn.

It currently has 301 questions, 11 followers, and no excerpt or wiki.

Some uses:

- Mathematical calculation in code. Should any code that includes `x+y` have this tag?
- Mathematical calculations not in code. Is this even on topic here?
- Date 'calculations' - determining a date by manipulating some values.
- Calculations within spreadsheets

I don't see the tag adding anything of value to the questions I've sampled, and most of the time it just seems like tag filler vaguely relevant to whatever is being asked.

On a related note, the [calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calculated) tag was already [burned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303510/868546), and this tag feels quite similar.

If this is not the right process to handle this, or I've missed a part of the process, feel free to elaborate.

Comment: Title suggestion: `Subtract [calculation]`

Comment: We do have [tag:date-calculation] as a synonym for [tag:date-arithmetic]. Any questions with date calculations can be moved to that tag. We also have [tag:math], but I'm not sure that's a good tag.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I approve! Is it ok to change the title with fun suggestions?

Comment: @Drise Do it! If someone takes exception they'll just revert it.

Comment: @Drise it's the standard for tag burnination request

Comment: So there seems to be support for this, now what?

Comment: Diskussed here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402952/when-is-it-acceptable-to-post-a-duplicate-burnination-request?cb=1

Comment: While the [tag:calculation] tag does no good, it does no real harm either.  There are now enough questions tagged with it that manual removal would be painful.  At least one question has only this tag (but it should probably have an Excel-related tag).  Cleaning up the not very interesting set of questions would be painful.  I think it might be best just to let this meander on as it has: unloved, unused by the cognoscenti, misused by the novices.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled on this tag today and thought it should be burninated. It seems not to have gotten visibility the first time it was proposed.

2 years and 7 months later, [calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calculation) has accrued 918 questions.

There are 18 watchers, but I don't know what they're watching for, except perhaps as an easy way to identify low quality questions to close.

The 10 most recent questions (50% closed):

- Calculation issues (debugging)
- Printing a sum (closed)
- Using `Math.pow` (debugging, closed)
- Calculating points to level up (closed)
- Calculating complex numbers
- Calculating in a db with null values
- Calculating in grep with a null byte
- Java exponentiation with large numbers (closed)
- Calculating largest and second largest number in C
- Results of a calculation in HTML (closed)

Continuing, topics range across all manner of calculations in all manner of programming languages.  The top answerer has answered 11 questions (earning 23 upvotes toward their 563K rep) and the second top answered 8 (earning 8 upvotes toward 1M+ rep). Everyone else has 3 or fewer.

The 10 highest upvoted questions have almost nothing in common:

- Calculating db size
- Subtracting a month from a day
- Finding the biggest difference in an array
- Calculating response times (performance)
- Cumulative multiplication in a db
- Calculating a square
- Excel/VBA's `Application.Calculation`
- CSS Dynamic Height difference
- Converting hours to minutes
- Calculating liquid nicotine strength

Only 85 of the 918 have more than one upvote. 124 have downvotes (but more were likely roomba'd). 72 are closed.

At the rate of 7 in the last week and 28 in the last month, this tag is only going to grow.  Hard to say that it's attracting low quality posts, but it's a conveniently useless tag appended to such posts, possibly in place of better tags.

The [Burnination Criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071):

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Most of the questions involve calculation.  Many hundreds of thousands of more questions on the site involve calculation without this tag.

And it's as ambiguous as mathematics.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

When performing calculations with code, it is. But that is the vast majority of programming.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Given the 20 specific question examples above, clearly no.

**Recommendation:**

Burn the tag immediately.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for bringing this back to the surface. I wasn't sure what was next in the process, and it looks like my question last go around never got answered. What is needed to actually get this done?

Comment: Attention of the community, really. I'm just a user like you, though, so no special knowledge. I figured by answering this would at least rise to the top of the active question list and get a few more views.